# C# driver Mongo $lookup fix

Tags: c#, mongodb

Can anyone  help me understand why I get the following: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in the last line of the method. My goal is to build a self lookup in the same collection that I am querying. I assume it has something to do with the driver not being able to serialize a model correctly but I am unable to understand why this is happening.

```cs
public void CanGetAggregatedComponents()
    {

        PipelineStageDefinition<ComponentRecordDataModel, AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel> lookup;

        lookup = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Lookup<ComponentRecordDataModel,
            ComponentRecordDataModel,
            AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel>(
            _mongoContext.Collection,
            local => local.RecordAlignments,
            foreign => foreign.Id,
            (AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel lookupResult) =>lookupResult
        );

      //  var expectedLookup =
        //    @"{$lookup: { from: 'componentRecord', localField: 'recordAlignments', foreignField: '_id', as: 'alignedToRecord' } }";

        var rendered = lookup.Render(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<ComponentRecordDataModel>(),
           BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your lookup is probably null. Try this:

```
public void CanGetAggregatedComponents()
    {

        PipelineStageDefinition<ComponentRecordDataModel, AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel> lookup;

        lookup = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Lookup<ComponentRecordDataModel,
            ComponentRecordDataModel,
            AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel>(
            _mongoContext.Collection,
            local => local.RecordAlignments,
            foreign => foreign.Id,
            (AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel lookupResult) =>lookupResult
        );

      //  var expectedLookup =
        //    @"{$lookup: { from: 'componentRecord', localField: 'recordAlignments', foreignField: '_id', as: 'alignedToRecord' } }";
   if(lookup !=null)
   {
        var rendered = lookup.Render(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<ComponentRecordDataModel     >(),BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);
   }
}
```

or this

```
public void CanGetAggregatedComponents()
    {

        PipelineStageDefinition<ComponentRecordDataModel, AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel> lookup;

        lookup = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Lookup<ComponentRecordDataModel,
            ComponentRecordDataModel,
            AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel>(
            _mongoContext.Collection,
            local => local.RecordAlignments,
            foreign => foreign.Id,
            (AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel lookupResult) =>lookupResult
        );

      //  var expectedLookup =
        //    @"{$lookup: { from: 'componentRecord', localField: 'recordAlignments', foreignField: '_id', as: 'alignedToRecord' } }";

        var rendered = lookup?.Render(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<ComponentRecordDataModel>(),
           BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);

    }
```

Comment: The lookup is not null. It contains the correct input/output and operator. The collection is of type `ComponentRecordDataModel`, not sure if I need to register `AggregatedAlignedComponentRecordDataModel ` in order for this to work.

Comment: ok then what about BsonSerializer? is that null, or SerializerRegistry? Have you checked those?